# Get all jobs in a View in active choice parameters using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am quite new to Jenkins and pipelines.
I have multiple jobs running in a view which needs to be say enabled and disabled at certain times.

I am able to get all the jobs and enable or disable it, I did as below

```
 for (item in Jenkins.instance.getView("Test").items) {
                    println("\nJob: $item.name")
                    def status = Jenkins.instance.getItem("$item.name").isBuildable()
                    println ("\nJob $item.name is Buildable : $status ")
                        if (params.job_action == 'disable'){
                            Jenkins.instance.getItem("$item.name").setDisabled(true)
                        }
                        if (params.job_action == 'enable') {
                            Jenkins.instance.getItem("$item.name").setDisabled(false)
                        }
                    }
```

Instead using for loop using list of jobs in code i want it to pass as parameter. like jobs can be selected in active choice parameters using check boxes or multi select option etc.

I tried somethings but its not giving an output in parameters instead its coming as blank.
TIA.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate? So you want a parameter that has a Job from a specific View?

Comment: Yes, thats right. in view i have many jobs. and i need that list as parameter where i can select which jobs i can disable or enable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            name: 'JobName',
            description: 'Parameter that displays all jobs in a view.',
            filterable: true,
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: '''
                        return ['Error: The script failed or it is not allowed by Jenkins. Check Script approval from General Settings.']
                    '''
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script: '''
                        return jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getView("myViewName").items.collect { job -> return job.displayName }
                    '''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])


pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo "${env.JobName}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the fallback script mentions, this script needs to be accepted in Script approval from General Settings. Make sure to set `sandbox: false`. Besides that, it is pretty straight forward. If you need help with the Active Choices Plugin maybe `<your_jenkins_url>/pipeline-syntax` > Snippet Generator > properties could come in handy.